# Css Transform not working as expected on mobile iphone and ipad

Tags: jquery, css

Great day!

Having a bit of a problem on the said subject above.
On a certain page I have multiple gears than spins with speed depending on scroll.

However once I move with the screen vertically I can see the gears jitters quite fast.

Would appreciate any insights on what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {//GEAR SPINS
    var theta = jQuery(window).scrollTop() ;
        jQuery('.left-wheel').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + theta/2 + 'deg)' });
        jQuery('.right-wheel').css({ transform: 'rotate(-' + theta/2 + 'deg)' });
        afterscroll = theta/2;
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle?